# Регулярное выражение для валидации домена и поддомена

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь создать регулярное выражение, валидирующее следующие требования:

1. Возможно одновременное использование кириллицы и цифр (без пробелов и спец. символов, разрешен дефис и точка);
2. Возможно одновременное использование латиницы и цифр (без пробелов и спец. символов, разрешен дефис и точка);
3. Невозможно одновременное использование кириллицы и латиницы;
4. Первый символ может быть цифрой;
5. Невозможно использование подряд два и более раз символа дефис или точка;
6. Возможно использование символа точка два раза, но не подряд;
7. Цифры могут повторяться. Буквы - не более двух раз  подряд. Дефис может быть только между буквами без дублирования (см. п.5). Дефис не может быть перед точкой или сразу после ее.

На данный момент, наваял такую "аббракадабру":

```
/(?!.*(.)\1)^(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.\-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.(com|org|ru|net))+$/gm
```

Вроде как условия мне необходимые выполняет, кроме ввода двух одинаковых  подряд букв.

Comment: и как успехи, что получилось на текущий момент?

Comment: все, кроме: не дает ввести подряд две одинаковые буквы или цифры

Comment: У вас некоторая путаница в требованиях: дефис нигде не упоминается в разрешённых символах и тут же запрещается его удваивание подряд. И про две одинаковые буквы или цифры (требование из комментария) в тексте вопроса ничего нет.